# Detener un bluce infinito Do While VBA

Tags: excel, vba

alguien tiene idea de como puede detener un bucle infinito Do while con otra macro en VBA excel.
Necesito generar 2 CTA a la macro, una para iniciar y otra para poder pararla, pero mientras el bucle se este ejecutado no es posible clicar sobre algún otro botón en excel.

El código quiero poder detener es este:

```
  Sub Grafico()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


  Dim wks As Worksheet
  'SE INDICA QUE SELECCIONE EL GRÁFICO DE LA HOJA DE CÁLCULO ACTIVA
  Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(8)
  'wks.ChartObjects("Gráfico 1").Select
DoEvents


Dim Inicial, Final, delta As Date



delta = Hoja8.Range("C3").Value
Inicial = Hoja8.Range("C1").Value
Final = Hoja8.Range("C2").Value

Do While Hoja8.Range("a3") <> 8
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Inicial = Inicial + delta
Hoja8.Range("C1") = Inicial
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
'
DoEvents

Final = Inicial + delta
Hoja8.Range("C2") = Final
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

DoEvents
'ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Stop
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
wks.ChartObjects("Gráfico 1").Activate
Application.ActiveChart.Refresh
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))


'wks.ChartObjects("Gráfico 1").Activate

DoEvents

'Debug.Print "Final"
'Stop
Loop

End Sub
```

Muchas gracias a alguien que pueda darme alguna idea.

Comment: Con otra macro no podes... no se que tratas de hacer, pero no deberias tener un bloque infinito... no es muy logico en vba....

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, es una aplicación que se alojara en un servidor e ira mostrando unas gráficas de control en tiempo real.

Comment: desde excel? raro... en fin... no podes cortar un proceso salvo que cierres excel... vba es un lenguaje muy basico.. no hay threads ni cosas asi... igual, se supone que con el doevents deberias recibir eventos de botones....

Comment: Las graficas están dentro de un form de excel? Si es así, puede capturar el control de teclado desde vba y, por ejemplo, pulsando la tecla F detener el while. Confirma que está dentro de un form y te indicaría como hacerlo